# Significado de ?: ?= ?! ?<= ?<! em uma regex

Tags: regex

Em várias regex notei alguns simbolos que não parecem ser parte da captura mas algum tipo de funcionalidade. Gostaria de saber o nome ou termo desses simbolos e qual é a funcionalidade de cada um.

```
?:
?=
?!
?<=
?<!
```

Comment: Depende da linguagem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Se estiver se referindo a regexes do .Net, usando a classe [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), esses símbolos podem ser usados ao iniciar um grupo com parenteses:

`(` + simbolos + ... + `)`

O que significam:

- `?:` Grupo não capturado: indica um grupo que não constará na lista de grupos capturados... note que isso vai ser considerado normalmente dentro do match, só não será um grupo, por exemplo:

  String analisada: `abc. 123 xpto<fim>`
     Regex: `\w+(?:\.|<fim>)`
     Matches: `abc.`, `xpto<fim>`

Os outros são assertivas, sem captura, e tampouco avançam na leitura:

- `?=` **Lookahead positivo:** isso é uma assertiva, que verifica se o grupo **pode** ser encontrado **iniciando-se** na posição que se encontra, mas sem capturar nem avançar na leitura da string que está sendo analisada, por exemplo:

  Ler palavras que acontecem antes de um ponto (`.`)
     String analisada: `123. xpto.`
     Regex: `\b\w+\b(?=\.)`
     Matches: `123`, `xpto`
- `?!` **Lookahead negativo:** isso é uma assertiva, que verifica se o grupo **não pode** ser encontrado **iniciando-se** na posição que se encontra, mas sem capturar nem avançar na leitura da string que está sendo analisada, por exemplo:

  Ler palavras que não acontecem antes de um ponto (`.`)
     String analisada: `123 xpto abc.`
     Regex: `\b\w+\b(?!\.)`
     Matches: `123`, `xpto`
- `?<=` **Lookbehind positivo:** isso é uma assertiva, que verifica se o grupo **pode** ser encontrado **terminando-se** na posição que se encontra, mas sem capturar nem avançar na leitura da string que está sendo analisada, por exemplo:

  Ler palavras que acontecem após um ponto (`.`)
     String analisada: `abc. 123 xpto.`
     Regex: `(?<=\.\s*)\b\w+\b`
     Matches: `123`
- `?<!` **Lookbehind negativo:** isso é uma assertiva, que verifica se o grupo **não pode** ser encontrado **terminando-se** na posição que se encontra, mas sem capturar nem avançar na leitura da string que está sendo analisada, por exemplo:

  Ler palavras que não acontecem após um ponto (`.`)
     String analisada: `abc. 123 xpto.`
     Regex: `(?<!\.\s*)\b\w+\b`
     Matches: `acb`, `xpto`

Se for do seu interesse, eu costumo usar essa ferramenta para trabalhar com regexes no C#:

http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/1.4/

Comment: Muito show de bola. +1. Sempre que esquecer, vou vir nessa pergunta

Comment: +1 só gostaria de frisar que isso não é específico do .Net, mas algo padronizado, disponível num grande número de *engines* de regex. O suporte (principalmente a *lookbehind*) varia, mas a sintaxe é a mesma em todas elas.

Answer (score 6):

**Lookahead** é uma forma de procurar strings que tenham ou não um determinado final. É utilizado (`?⁼..`) para o positivo, ou seja, que terminem com; e (`?!..`) para o negativo, ou seja, que não termina com.

**Lookbehind** faz o mesmo que o **lookahead**, porém, como o próprio nome diz, não procura depois, mas sim antes, da string dita. (`?<=..`) para o positivo e (`?<!..`) para o negativo.

Exemplo, considere a sequência `foobarbarfoo`.

```
bar(?=bar)    encontra o primeiro bar.
bar(?!bar)    encontra o segundo bar.
(?<=foo)bar   encontra o primeiro bar.
(?<!foo)bar   encontra o segundo bar.
```

Você também pode combiná-los:

```
(?<=foo)bar(?=bar)   encontra o primeiro bar.
```

Veja essa ferramenta online([**RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/)) ela o ajuda a criar expressões, tal como identificar tipos, há também exemplos.

[**Aqui**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) explica mais detalhadamente sobre o assunto.

<sub>*Em breve atualizarei a resposta com mais informações.*</sub>

Comment: O breve momento chegou?